# Telnet to Python server gets stuck

Tags: python, telnet

I am preparing a demo, and I wanted to use a simple server for it, instead of nginx or any other popular server.

I got the following one from python official page:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

So, I run it, and everything seems to be fine:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

If I go to the browser, or curl the IP address, it works just fine:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [31/May/2019 09:36:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [31/May/2019 09:37:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [31/May/2019 09:37:46] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [31/May/2019 09:39:03] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [31/May/2019 09:39:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [31/May/2019 09:39:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [31/May/2019 09:39:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Now, when I connect to the server through `telnet`, and I do `GET`, the server get stuck:

```
$ telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 8000
Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
...It just hangs here foever...
```

When I hit on `ctrl+c` on the server, it shows me an exception that happened, that I don't know how to interpret in this context:

```
^C----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('xx.xx.xx.xx', 47346)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 313, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 341, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 354, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 681, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 422, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 400, in handle_one_request
    if not self.parse_request():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 334, in parse_request
    _class=self.MessageClass)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 206, in parse_headers
    line = fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 576, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
KeyboardInterrupt
----------------------------------------
```

I also SSH-ed into the same machine where the server is running and did the request connecting to the localhost. Hanged too.

I would like to know:

1. How is `telnet` GET different to other GETs.
2. At python server level, what does the exception mean, and how to solve it.

Comment: Did you send **two** `\r\n` to complete the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. How is telnet GET different to other GETs.

`telnet` is not different here. Your server is hanging because it is waiting for you to finish typing your GET request. For this, you just need to press `Enter` twice, after typing your GET request.

This is because:

- One `CR-LF` character is required to end the message header section of the HTTP request (as specified [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html))
- another one is the actual `CR-LF` that tells `telnet` you finished entering input

> 2. At python server level, what does the exception mean, and how to solve it.

This is just a consequence of you pressing `Ctrl + C`, thus interrupting the Python process running your `SimpleHTTPServer`.

Comment: It's not `telnet` which reacts to the text, it's the remote server.

Comment: yes I know, the text (I guess you mean, the exception) is just thrown because you pressed Ctrl+ C. But your problem with `telnet` handing is on client-side only. See my updated answer above.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue.

Comment: "Telnet is hanging because it's waiting` - no, it's not hanging, it's doing its job, relaying everything you type to the server over the network and printing out everything the server responds. The *server* is stuck waiting because the HTTP request you typed in is not yet complete.

Comment: @tripleee you are right, I just updated my answer above to make it more accurate. Thanks!